# EntityMetadataWrapperException when accessing empty entity body. How can I test if body is empty first?

Tags: entities

The following call

```
$body = $entity->body->value->value();
```

throw the following error

```
EntityMetadataWrapperException : Unable to get the data property value as the parent data structure is not set. dans EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyValue()
```

when the body is empty.

How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

Just simply see the value is empty

```
if($node_wrapper->body->value() != ""){
 //Evaluates true
}
```

or use a try catch

```
try{
 echo $entity->body->value->value();
}catch(Exception $e){
  echo "Value does not exist continue";
}
```

Comment: Catching an `EntityMetadataWrapperException` would be better, but yeah `try...catch` is the way to go